# Strict upper and lower bounds of a sum (Big-Theta)

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, summation, asymptotics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to find a function f(k) such that $S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1}(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)=\Theta(f(k))$. What I have done so far:

Ignoring the floor asymptotically we get: 

$$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1}(\sqrt{n})=\Theta(f(k))$$

$g(n)=\sqrt{n}$ is a monotonically increasing function so we can approximate the sum by integrals:

$$\int_0^{k^2-1}\sqrt{x}dx\leq\sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1}(\sqrt{n})\leq\int_1^{k^2}\sqrt{x}dx$$

Let $A=\int_0^{k^2-1}\sqrt{x}dx$ and $B=\int_1^{k^2}\sqrt{x}dx$

Starting from the second integral:

$B=\int_1^{k^2}x^{1/2}dx=[\frac23x^{3/2}]_1^{k^2}=\frac23k^3-\frac23=O(k^3)$ (Big-Oh notation) beacause for each $n\geq n_0=1, c=\frac23$ the following is true: $0 < B\leq ck^3=\frac23k^3$

So that's an upper bound for $S_k$ that is $S_k=O(k^3)$. As far as I know $S_k=\Omega(k^3)$ and this way $S_k=\Theta(k^3)$. But I cannot prove the lower bound. For A the following is true:

$A=\int_0^{k^2-1}x^{1/2}dx=[\frac23x^{3/2}]_0^{k^2-1}=\frac23(k^2-1)^{3/2}$

How can I proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $1\leqslant i\leqslant k$ and every $i^2\leqslant n\leqslant(i+1)^2-1$, one has $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor=i$ hence
$$S_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{k=i^2}^{(i+1)^2-1}i=\sum_{i=1}^ki\,(2i+1)=\frac16k(k+1)(4k+5),$$ hence $$S_k=\Theta(k^3).$$

Comment: Can you please explain the answer in more detail? Basically, I do not understand why Sk is equal to this double sum and what's the logic behind your thought?

Comment: Huh? For every sequence $(x_n)$, $$\sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1}x_n=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{n=i^2}^{(i+1)^2-1}x_n.$$ This is summing the sum slice after slice...

Comment: I understand why this is true, but what are the steps to prove it according to the properties of summation? As far as I know, this is not among the basic identities of summation.

Comment: Is it not? Try item 6 [there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#General_manipulations).

Comment: Yes, the general idea is to break a large sum into smaller non-overlapping parts. But what's the proof that the number of occurrences of $x_n$ in the double sum is equal to the number of occurrences of $x_n$ in the initial sum i.e. $k^2 - 1$ ?

Comment: ?? Each $x_n$ appears exactly *once* in both cases.

Comment: That's not what I mean. Let's consider the simplest case $x_n=1$ for every n. In that case, why $(k^2-1)*1$ (first sum) is equal to $\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{n=i^2}^{(i+1)^2-1}1$ (double sum)?

Comment: Because of the disjoint union $$\{1,2,\ldots,k^2-1\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^k\{i^2,i^2+1,\ldots,(i+1)^2-1\}.$$